# vboxapi for python3

Tags: virtualbox, python3

I need to spawn/kill virtual box machines using python3.

There is a module called `pyvbox`, but it does not work because the `vboxapi` package is incompatible with python3.

If I try to import `vboxapi`:

```
>>> import vboxapi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'vboxapi'

>>> import virtualbox
>>> pool = virtualbox.pool.MachinePool("ubuntu1")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/virtualbox/pool.py", line 76, in __init__
    with self._lock() as session:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 59, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/virtualbox/pool.py", line 85, in _lock
    vbox = VirtualBox()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/virtualbox/library_ext/vbox.py", line 21, in __init__
    manager = virtualbox.Manager()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/virtualbox/__init__.py", line 103, in __init__
    with import_vboxapi() as vboxapi:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 59, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/virtualbox/__init__.py", line 34, in import_vboxapi
    import vboxapi
ImportError: No module named 'vboxapi'
```

There is a package in `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/vboxapi`, but it is incompatible with python3, for instance because of

```
File "/usr/lib/virtualbox/sdk/bindings/xpcom/python/xpcom/__init__.py", line 128
    except IOError, why:
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is there a way to use vboxapi with python3, which is the default python version on Ubuntu 16.06, or do I have to write such a package on my own?

(Optional) What is `xpcom`?

I run on `Linux Iwillnottellyoumyhostname 4.4.0-38-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 6 15:42:33 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`.

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: @Tjorriemorrie No the vboxapi is still incompatible with python3. By the way I checked out the sourcecode of vboxapi and it is just a mess. The programmer  did not get basic concepts of python and it is really hard to understand the code, because he keeps deleting class instances to "keep [his] namespace clean".

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to use vboxapi with python3. You can use this: [vboxapi-py3](https://github.com/GreatFruitOmsk/vboxapi-py3)